# TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I get the following error when I run `npm start` on my react project. Everything was working fine until I added a few scripts and installed `recharts`. I've tried `npm install`, `npm cache clean --force`, removed `package-lock.json` and installed again, stash my changes but nothing seems to work.

```
home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
    at Function.getCompilationHooks (/home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:193:10)
    at /home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/dist/index.js:57:42
    at _next38 (eval at create (/home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:50:1)
    at _next16 (eval at create (/home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:97:1)
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:133:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (/home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (/home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1055:26)
    at /home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1099:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/home/bisola/Documents/pro/gitcoin/subquery/explorer/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! explorer@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the explorer@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bisola/.npm/_logs/2021-12-27T20_51_51_714Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Somewhat. But basically, you have to take a close look at version of dependencies like react-scripts, webpack, react-error-overlay and babel and avoid duplicates. I cleared node_modules, package-lock.json and use yarn install. I had to manually make a number of changes to package.json including adding `"resolutions": {"react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"}`